# XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/xdebug.log' while reading response header from upstream

Tags: php, docker, xdebug

I am using docker for developing, which worked without any problems at all until I had no space left on my disk (my Ubuntu partition is only 30G). So I deleted all containers and images which weren't running/used anymore and had enough space.

After starting my application again, I'm now getting a `ContextErrorException` with the following message

`Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected`

When I look into the `error.log`, this is the content

```
2017/04/29 12:53:13 [error] 13#13: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/xdebug.log'" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: app, request: "GET /admin/dashboard HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost:8080"
2017/04/29 12:53:24 [error] 13#13: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/xdebug.log'.
PHP message: XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/xdebug.log'.
PHP message: XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/xdebug.log'.
PHP message: XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/xdebug.log'.
PHP message: XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/xdebug.log'.
PHP message: XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/xdebug.log'.
PHP message: XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/xdebug.log'.
PHP message: XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/xdebug.log'.
PHP message: XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/xdebug.log'.
PHP message: XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/xdebug.log'.
PHP message: XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/xdebug.log'.
PHP message: XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/xdebug.log'.
PHP message: XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/xdebug.log'.
PHP message: XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/xdebug.log'" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: app, request: "GET /admin/dashboard HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost:8080"
```

I did the following steps in both environments (docker-container and host system)
I went into `/var/log/` and saw that there was no file `xdebug.log` so I created the file and - just for testing purpose - gave them `777` rights and changed the owner/group to the same as my project files/docker files

The error still exists, however. I even deleted ALL container and images, not only the unused one, and built it completely from scratch. This doesn't seem like a Docker error, because it worked without problems until the disk space was full, right?

This is the result of `php -i | grep xdebug`

```
xdebug
xdebug support => enabled
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => * => *
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => * => *
xdebug.dump.POST => * => *
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => * => *
xdebug.dump.SERVER => * => *
xdebug.dump.SESSION => * => *
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => php-debug => php-debug
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 250 => 250
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => On => On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => 192.168.0.10 => 192.168.0.10
xdebug.remote_log => /var/log/xdebug.log => /var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 4 => 4
```

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: make certain that /var/log/xdebug.log and /var/log directory are writeable by the http process owner.

Comment: I did. On my host machine it has to be `{myusername}:{myusername}` since all other files are the same (I guess). And on the host machine all files have `100:100` as owner/group. I even added a `777` to the file. The `/var/log` on host has `775`, and even setting it to 777 doesn't work, sadly.

Comment: Can you include the output of `ls -l /var/log/xdebug.log` please?

Comment: Sorry @EdsonMedina, I already reinstalled Ubuntu. :|